# How to add a 3-second delay to this cookie-based pop-up?

Tags: javascript, cookies, settimeout

This `.popup-overlay-b` container is set to "display: none" in CSS but has a javascript code forcing it to show if there's no previous cookie session and it's supposed to expire after 1 day. I just need to give it a few seconds delay before it shows.

This code works without the delay

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!Cookies.get('alert')) { 
      $('.popup-overlay-b').show(); 
      Cookies.set('alert', true, { expires: 1 });
    }
});
</script>
```

This is what I've attempted and doesn't work

```
$(document).setTimeout(function(){
    if (!Cookies.get('alert')) { 
      $('.popup-overlay-b').show(); 
      Cookies.set('alert', true, { expires: 1 });
    }
},3000);
</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is a function on the `window` object, not `$(document)`. Just call it "plain", like `setTimeout(someFunction, 3000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!Cookies.get('alert')) {
      $('.popup-overlay-b').show();
      Cookies.set('alert', true, { expires: 1});
    }
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: works! Thank you, never thought of this method, I was way off.

Comment: My pleasure! You weren't too far off.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `await sleep(<duration>);`